# What's wrong with: LinkedList<String> stringList = new LinkedList<String>();

Tags: java

When I try:

```
LinkedList<String> stringList = new LinkedList<String>();
```

I get the following compilation error:

```
type LinkedList does not take parameters
```

What am I missing?  Can't you do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Check to make sure you don't have a compiled class named `LinkedList` in the same directory. (Especially since "linked list" is a common term, and it is something that people often try to implement as beginners.) This is important if you import your classes using something like `import java.util.*;`, because the `*` imports on-demand, so if there is a class with the same name in the package already, then that class is used and the `java.util.LinkedList` is not imported.

Comment: Or better yet, look at your imports and make sure you're actually importing java.util.LinkedList and not some other LinkedList

Comment: You guessed it, good job.

Just the other day, I had coded a simple LinkedList for practice, I shouldn't have forgotten so soon.

Comment: You guessed it perfectly.

Answer (score 11):

Are you possibly compiling against a JDK 1.4 or earlier? Or do you have your language setting in your build or IDE set to pre-5.0 (so no generics support)?

By the way, the best way to do that is

```
List<String> stringList = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Use the interface rather than the implementation wherever possible.

That being said, assuming you're compiling against a JDK 5.0+, have your language settings set to Java 5+ and that is a java.util.LinkedList then your code is perfectly valid.

Comment: Actually, the best way to do that is to use Google Collections :-)

`List<String> stringList = Lists.newLinkedList();`

Comment: Hmm . . . I'm using JDK 7.  I'll try compiling with JDK 6.  
I'd hate to say that I've found a bug in the compiler, but it isn't yet officially released, so it's possible.

Comment: Classic newbie mistake: "I've found a bug in the compiler."  It might be possible, but it's vanishingly small compared to probability that you're the one who's made the mistake.  Banish the thought - it'll be the best thing you learn from this episode

Comment: Open a command shell, type "java -version", and see what you get.  That's the only way to be sure about the version you're using.

Comment: Also work out what your JAVA_HOME is. echo %JAVA_HOME% on Windows, typically echo $JAVA_HOME on Linux/Unix (at a command line).

Comment: I'm a bit embarrassed to have publicly blamed the compiler.  In any case, Mr. newacct guessed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Don't take the class name as `class LinkedList` instead you can take `class LinkedListDemo` and rest of the declaration `LinkedList<String> t = new LinkedList<String>();` should be there and it will compile perfectly.

Comment: When you type an answer, read the notes about using markdown.  Then you will be able to type `LinkedList<String>` and view it correctly.

In any case, thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

I had a same problem and I figured out that I mistakenly used:
 import java.awt.List;
and got the following error message:
"Type List doesn't take paramaters"

Use this instead

import java.util.List;

Answer (score 0):

You have used `import java.util.*;`

You will not face any issue if you use `import java.util.LinkedList;`

Comment: Thanks for you contribution.

It's often useful to check the date when answering questions -- this one is more than ten years old, so I wasn't needing another answer, I got the help I needed some time ago.

Sometimes it's useful to answer old questions, when there isn't yet a useful answer, but this question had several good answers already.

Answer (score 0):

Type something like this :

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

class LinkedListDemo { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    LinkedList <String> list=new LinkedList <String> ();

}}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I asked this question in 2009. New answers are not really needed.

Comment: for someone else