# why isn't this statement working?

Tags: java

i've been following a tutorial and come across this section of code in a linked list. Could you please help me distinguish what the problem is, thanks

```
 String[] things = {"apples", "noobs", "pwnge", "bacon", "goats"};
       List<String> list1 = new LinkedList<String>();
       for (String x : things)
           list1.add(x);

error: type LinkedList does not take parameters 
List<String> list1 = new LinkedList<String>();
```

the error is on the second line of the code, any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the error? This code works fine for me.

Comment: error: type LinkedList does not take parameters
           List<String> list1 = Is what I'm getting which isn't much help

Comment: That error message should belong to the question. To add it there use [edit] option.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217868/whats-wrong-withlinkedliststring-stringlist-new-linkedliststring

Comment: Could you show us *exactly* the code you have? You might have a subtle bug which you didn't reproduce in the question because you rewrote it instead of copy-pasting.

Comment: Yeah, if you have your own implementation of `LinkedList`, you might be confusing Java into using that instead of the system-provided `java.util.LinkedList`.

Comment: The problem was that I had named the main class LinkedList and the compiler was getting confused, after renaming main class to LinkedListDemo all errors were resolved, thanks.

Comment: In general, you should avoid naming a class with a common class name. e.g. you can create you own class called `String` but you shouldn't. ;)

Comment: @Ashraf Purno This doesn't explain the equestion I have asked.