# Why does type LinkedList not take parameters?

Tags: java

I am trying to debug a java code which was written using LinkedList. 
Here is the code.

```
import java.util.*;  

public class TestCollection7{  
public static void main(String args[]){  

LinkedList<String> al=new LinkedList<String>();  
   al.add("Ravi");  
   al.add("Vijay");  
   al.add("Ravi");  
   al.add("Ajay");  

   Iterator<String> itr=al.iterator();  
   while(itr.hasNext()){  
     System.out.println(itr.next());  
    }  
  }  
}
```

I get this error.

```
TestCollection7.java:6: error: type LinkedList does not take parameters
LinkedList<String> al=new LinkedList<String>();
```

When I run this code with Java in Windows 10, there is no error. But in Linux, I get the error above.

For the source of the code, this is
[the website where the code came from](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-linkedlist).

Comment: Are you using Java6 ?! this is too old!

Comment: `java.util.LinkedList` **does** take 1 type parameter.

Comment: What versions of Java are you running on each platform?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217868/whats-wrong-withlinkedliststring-stringlist-new-linkedliststring check this one

Comment: Do you have your own non-generic `LinkedList` class in your project?

Comment: Do you have a class elsewhere called LinkedList?

Comment: It's Java 10.0.1, 2018-04-17

Comment: @YCF_L It looks like line 6, not version 6.

Comment: Seems that you're using a JDK/JVM 5 or prior in your linux env. Besides that, code in that site seems very old, I'd suggest using another source to learn proper Java coding.

Comment: ah this is correct @rgettman

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: "type LinkedList does not take parameters" means that particular version of Java is well aware of generics. It must be what rgettman is saying.

Comment: Dear all, what if I try put 
`import java.util.LinkedList;  
 import java.util.Iterator;  ` at the top?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific than "in Linux".  Your code compiles fine for me in Linux, using the `javac` of OpenJDK 1.8.0_171.  I would expect the same with any Java compiler conforming to any remotely modern version of Java, on any platform.

Comment: Hi all, I have tried putting `import java.util.LinkedList; import java.util.Iterator; ` at the top, there is no more error. But I am very doubtful. Why can't I just use `import java.util.*;` in Java 10?

Comment: @LiuBei You have to remove your `LinkedList` class from the directory or refer to `LinkedList` with `java.util.LinkedList`.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you don't have a compiled class named `LinkedList` in the same directory. Also, try to use a variable of the interface type, `List`. That allows you to easily swap out the implementations.

```
List<String> al =new LinkedList<>();
```

Comment: rm LinkedList.java would work!